# UITableView doesn't load data - Swift 2 with Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, swift2

I'm trying to make a page to show who a user is following in a table. Everything seems pretty clear to me, but for some reasons this code is not loading my data. The following is my following page controller :

import Foundation
import Parse

```
class FollowingController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    var profileId : String = String()

    @IBOutlet weak var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    @IBOutlet weak var topTitleBar: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var mainBox: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var resultData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    func loadData(){

        resultData.removeAllObjects()

        loadingIndicator.hidden = false
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

        var counter = 0
        let followingQuery = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
        followingQuery.whereKey("following", equalTo: profileId)
        followingQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    let userQuery = PFUser.query()
                    userQuery?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: object["followed"] as! String)
                    userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users, error ) -> Void in
                        if let users = users {
                            for user in users{
                                let followed = user as! PFUser
                                self.resultData.addObject(followed)
                                counter++
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }

let array:NSArray = self.resultData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.resultData = NSMutableArray(array: array)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            if counter == 0 {
                //Handle no results
            }
        }

        loadingIndicator.hidden = true
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }



    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.loadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return resultData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell:FollowingCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FollowingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FollowingCell
        let user:PFUser = self.resultData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFUser

        let name = (user.objectForKey("firstName") as! String) + " " + (user.objectForKey("lastName") as! String)
        cell.name.text = name

        if let profilePicture = user.objectForKey("profilePicture") as? PFFile {
            profilePicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    let profileImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                    cell.profilePicture.image = profileImage
                }
            })
        }


        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    }

    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
    }

}
```

I created a custom class for my cell and called it FollowingCell. All the outlets are connected to the variables in the class as well as the table datasource & delegate to the ViewController! If you spot anything that might be causing this table not to display the data please let me know. Thanks.

EDIT : Found out the problem is that even though I load the resultData array in the for loop for each user, outside the findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock call the resultData count returns 0. So it's like if it's not actually updating the array. Anybody knows why could that be?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to reload the tableview

```
mytableview.reloadData()
```

everytime you load the data you have to reload the full table view or append cells to it..

And check the cell identifiers declared correctly in storyboard

Comment: I added it but it still won't work, I updated the code on the question if you wanna check out where I added it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. - Actually no error, there's just a warning from Parse for a long-running operation

Comment: That error is solved over here https://www.parse.com/questions/warnparseoperationonmainthread

Comment: Thanks but I think that should be just a warning because downloading the data takes a relatively long time. The table should still load the data though I think, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You might forget to set identifier for your Cell from Storyboard as "FollowingCell", double check it. Also reload the tableView.

Comment: I just updated the code in the question reloading the tableView data! I double checked the identifier and that should be correct!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, there was a problem when I reloaded the data outside the second query. Reloading the data inside the second query call and outside the inner one worked!